# PHP Find position and value of last Digit in string

Tags: php

```
$string = "hello 31 84 1 546 today 77 is 4 good";
```

How do I get the position of the last "4"?

How do I get the value "4"?

Comment: Do you need to find the last digit, whatever it may be, or are you looking specifically for the last `'4'` in the string?

Comment: The last digit.  I will not know what it is.

Comment: Will the string ever change to `hello 31 84 1 546 today 77 is 4 the good`? This type of string is unusual. You should show us the "real" string.

Comment: Answers don't belong in questions. Post your own "answer", Stack lets you do that. I've performed a rollback.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but I think this is what you're looking for?

```
$string = "hello 31 84 1 546 today 77 is 4 good";
if(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $numbers))
    $lastnum = end($numbers[0]);
```

1. Matching all of the grouped integers in your string
2. Put them into an array.
3. The last element of the array is the last number in the sentence.

### EDIT:

As @Michael says in the comment:

> And maybe, if the OP requires, remove the last digit from a
>   multi-digit number - e.g. if it ended with is 49 good, substr() to get
>   9 which is technically the last digit rather than 49 as this would
>   return. Unclear question though.

Comment: And maybe, if the OP requires, remove the last digit from a multi-digit number - e.g. if it ended with `is 49 good`, `substr()` to get `9` which is technically the _last digit_ rather than 49 as this would return. Unclear question though.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Missed that... added to my answer, thanks

Comment: Good point Michael. I needed that! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the answer:**

```
$s1 = "hello 31 84 1 546 today 77 is 894 good";

if(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $s1, $numbers)){

    $lastFullNum =      end($numbers[0]);               //eg. "894"
    $lastDigit =        substr($lastFullNum, -1);       //eg. "4"
    $lastDigitPos =     strrpos($s1, $lastDigit, 0);    //eg. "32"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match` to get the last digit(s), defining "last" as "that point from whence no more digits are to be found", i.e. "it's non-digits (\D) up to the end of the string ($)":

```
preg_match('#(\\d+)\\D*$#', $string, $gregs);
```

Now `$gregs[1]` contains the last digit**s**. (If you only want the *very last one*, omit the "+"). You may need a multiline modifier if the string contains carriage returns.

To get the digit(s)'s offset you need [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php):

```
$offset = strrpos($string, $gregs[1]);
```

Or you can use the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` option of [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
if (false !== preg_match('#(\\d+)\\D*$#', $string, $gregs, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    list ($digit, $offset) = $gregs[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array example;

```
<?php
  $s1 = "hello 31 84 1 546 today 77 is 894 good";
  $array = explode(' ',$s1);
  echo end($array) . '<br />';
  echo prev($array) . '<br />';
?>
```